# popoverPresentationController(_:willRepositionPopoverTo:in:) Trying to change the size of popUp on different orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I have a pop over and I am trying to change the width when the orientation changes. I get the width that I want when the popUp shows in the current orientation, but when I switch from .portrait -> .landscape I don't get the width that I want.It keeps the .portrait once for example.

I read the documentation about the popoverPresentationController(_:willRepositionPopoverTo:in:)

but I can't figure out how it works.
actually it doesn't even called when I change the orientation. The rest of the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate that I use they work correctly.

Is this the correct one for changing the size of the PopUp , or should I use something else ?

Any help? Thanks a lot

```
func popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>) {

        if popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController is PopUpTextPickerViewController{
            let viewFrame = popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController.view.frame

            let newRect = CGRect(x: viewFrame.origin.x, y: viewFrame.origin.y, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 100)
            let newView = UIView(frame: newRect)
            rect.pointee =  newRect
            view.pointee = newView

        }
        print("popoverPresentation:willRepositionPopOverTo")
    }

    //Shows the PopUpTextPickerViewController on the screen
    @IBAction func fontButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        subscribeToNotifications(notification: .popUpTextPickerViewController)
        let fontController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popUpTextPickerViewController") as! PopUpTextPickerViewController
        fontController.fontName = self.fontName
        fontController.fontSize = self.fontSize
        fontController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        fontController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        fontController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = fontButton
        fontController.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = .clear
        fontController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        fontController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 100)
        present(fontController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing below code in your parent view controller. UIKit calls this method before changing the size of a presented view controller’s view -

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize,
                        with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if let myVC = self.presentedViewController as? MyViewController {
            myVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: {yorWidth}, height: {yourHeight})
    }
}
```